# Can't get PHP to query anything with sqlite using PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm going off the Zend tutorial [here](http://devzone.zend.com/14/php-101-part-9-sqlite-my-fire_part-1/). It's a few years outdated, and the given PHP code doesn't work. I already have the sqlite database set up, which I did from the command line. From googling around, I decided to try PDO and ended up with the following:

```
<?php
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/phpstuff/sqlitedb/testdb.db";
$db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $filepath) or die('Could not open database');
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";
$result = $db->query($query);

echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=1>";
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$db = NULL;
?>
```

My header and footer that I include on every page still come up, but no table comes up, so I think that it's the query that isn't working. I'm at a loss as to why. I instead tried to use as my loop condition `while ($row = $result->fetchArray())`, and that failed, as well.

I did run `phpinfo()` to see if the PDO drivers were installed and `extension_loaded` to see if sqlite3 was installed. Both checked out. I also ran simple `echo` statements before and after the table printout, and both worked. It's just that the table isn't being generated at all. Does this perhaps have anything to do with my filepath? Permissions? PHP/sqlite versions? My server is running Ubuntu 12.04 Server and this file is located within the `phpstuff` directory listed above. Both `/sqlitedb` and `testdb.db` permissions are set to 777.

Update: changing the filepath to simply `/sqlite/testdb.db` yields the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`. Currently checking if this is a permissions issue and how to change it

Comment: Don't use `or die()` with PDO (or anything for that matter). The PDO constructor will throw a `PDOException` if it can't connect.

Comment: You should also enable error reporting during development. Put this at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Phil Thanks. This gives `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/phpstuff/phpsqlite.php on line 30`. Seems like PHP can't read from the database for some reason

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't a *solution* as such but the comments section is too small. In any case, it should help you get to the bottom of the problem.

First, enable error reporting

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can remove these lines once it goes to production.

Try using a better file path (I've always found `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to be unreliable, especially if you want to access the script via non-web methods). Also, set PDO to throw exceptions

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:' . __DIR__ . '/sqlitedb/testdb.db');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Chances are, your query is failing, thus `$result` is `false`. Enabling proper error handling an exceptions from PDO should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the solution from the error message `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database`. PHP was using sqlite3, but somehow the database was sqlite2, and apparently, sqlite3 is not backwards compatible. 

How did this happen, though? According to https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=39974, that one command should take care of everything, but I also had to explicitly get sqlite3 to make it work.